# matplotlib + tkinter in anaconda will not work even after reinstalling

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, anaconda

I am trying to use tkinter with matplotlib.

I get the below error when I try to do this. I have read every signal thread and articles I can find on this which have all said to pip uninstall then pip reinstall matplotlib which I did did many times with no joy.

this is the end I am getting

```
> 14, in <module>
> line for line in traceback.format_stack()
> matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
      matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
<
```

this below is what I am trying to import

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

I would really appreciate any advice on this.

The Full Error message is below

```
    n [1]: runfile('C:/Users/carl-/Desktop/Programing/Projects/Kitties                             
    Mastermind/SandBox.py', 
    wdir='C:/Users/carl-/Desktop/Programing/Projects/Kitties Mastermind')
    C:/Users/carl-/Desktop/Programing/Projects/Kitties 
    Mastermind/SandBox.py:2: UserWarning: 
    This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has 
    already
    been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, 
    matplotlib.pyplot,
    or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

    The backend was *originally* set to 
    'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline' by the following code:
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 245, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 229, in main
        kernel.initialize()
      File "<decorator-gen-124>", line 2, in initialize
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
        return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 464, in initialize
        self.init_code()
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\IPython\core\shellapp.py", line 260, in init_code
        self._run_exec_lines()
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\shellapp.py", line 286, in _run_exec_lines
        self.shell.run_cell(line, store_history=False)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
        return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2698, in run_cell
        interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2808, in run_ast_nodes
        if self.run_code(code, result):
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-1-e27d371d6baa>", line 1, in <module>
        get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2146, in magic
        return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2067, in 
      run_line_magic
        result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
      File "<decorator-gen-108>", line 2, in matplotlib
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\magic.py", line 187, in <lambda>
        call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py", line 99, in matplotlib
        gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2930, in 
      enable_matplotlib
        pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 307, in activate_matplotlib
        matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", 
      line 232, in switch_backend
        matplotlib.use(newbackend, warn=False, force=True)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1305, in use
        reload(sys.modules['matplotlib.backends'])
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 166, in 
      reload
        _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
      File "C:\Users\carl-\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
        line for line in traceback.format_stack()


      matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```

Comment: Can you show the *complete*  error traceback. This one seems to be cut, as there is no actual error shown.

Comment: Ohh sorry, Ok I have just edited the post with the fall error thanks for your time!

Comment: You are trying to use TkAgg backend in an environment which already has some other backend set (actually the message is pretty much trying to tell you exactly that). Now you need to tell us which exact environment that is. "In anaconda" is not actually precise enough because anaconda is just a bunch of things installed on your machine.

Comment: I am using the Ipython console inside of spider, so does this mean I need to find the code of the backed which is already installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IPython inside Spyder, the backend in use will be selected before actually putting typing any code. Changing the backend would hence require to change the automatic setting inside the spyder settings.

[image]

Any changes made here would require to restart Spyder.

Comment: WOW! I had no idea that was their!

Thank you so much for your help I would have spend days trying to work this out cheers!